# What event is rised when changing between two BorderContainers using TabBar component?

Tags: air, flex4, desktop-application

I am developing Adobe Air desktop application using Apache Flex 4.9.1 SDK. 
I am using a TabBar control in order to go through different windows. For a window I am using a BorderContainer control.

My question is:

Is there any event raised(in the BorderContainer control not in the TabBAr control) when you change from one window to another using the tabs. The event in TabBar is "change", but I need to capture this moment in the BorderContainer. I have tried "FocusOut", "Hide", "Deactive" events, but they are not raised. So does anybody knows what is happening in the BorderContainer when the tab is changed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would catch the CHANGE event of the TabBar and dispatch it to the windows children. Other events of the windows selves are not such informative as this one, because they can fire in other situations. Only the "guilty" component can control it appropriately, I think.

Comment: Yes I think you are right!
Probably the best way is the way you described.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Use the change event on the tab bar ..